# HelloJS /me API does not return complete results

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, hello.js

I'm quite new to HelloJS.

When I tried HelloJS '/me' API on the website. It returns

```
http://adodson.com/hello.js/#helloapi

base url: http://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me?
{
 id: "1234",
 email: "test@gmail.com",
 first_name: "R",
 gender: "male",
 last_name: "D",
 link: "http://www.facebook.com/1234",
 locale: "en_US",
 middle_name: "Kumar",
 name: "Demo",
 timezone: -7,
 updated_time: "2015-08-12T22:21:57+0000",
 verified: true,
 picture: "https://graph.facebook.com/1234/picture",
 thumbnail: "https://graph.facebook.com/1234/picture"
}
```

But when I call /me, I just get **name and id**. **Why**?

This is my code snippet.

```
hello.on('auth.login', function(auth) {
    var authNetwork = auth.network;
var getHelloApi = function(path){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    hello(authNetwork).api(path).then(function(json){
        deferred.resolve(json);
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}

// parse social data after we finish trying to get from hellojs api
$.when(getHelloApi('/me?'), getHelloApi('/me/friends')
).then(function(me, meFriends){
    var socialData = {};
    if(!$.isEmptyObject(me)){
        var basicProfileDataList = ["name", "email", "gender", "timezone", "locale"];
        $.each(basicProfileDataList, function() {
            if (me[this] != null) {
                suffix = this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
                socialData["social" + authNetwork.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + authNetwork.slice(1) + suffix] = me[this];
            }
        });
    }
```

I want to collect name, email,gender, timezone. Calling /me will give me all these in one API call on their website but not when I call it from my application.

Should I set some permission in the APP? What Am I missing?

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 1):

Search for "Declarative Fields" in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

You now have to specify the additional fields, for example:

```
/me?fields=name,email
```

Comment: But how is helloJS able to pull everything using /me without using any declarative fields?

Comment: you MUST use declarative fields, just use the api call i posted instead of a simple call to "/me"

Comment: Facebook lets apps define which version of their graph API to use per client-id. So //adodson.com is configured to use v2.3. Prior to v2.4 calls to this endpoint had more fields than by default. Latest HelloJS now explicitly uses v2.3 at the current time. I hope that clears it up.

Comment: you cannot use v2.3 for new apps. if you create an app, you can only use the latest api version that was out when you created it. you can't go back, it does not matter if HelloJS tries to use v2.3.